# Regex not returning what I ask it to select

Tags: c#, regex, testcomplete

I have a string like below:

```
MSH|^~\&|dgdgd|MSH6TOMSH4|Instrument|MSH4toMSH6|20230921104820+01:00||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|QPC0amoCwk+2uSHidYKB+Q|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^
MSA|AA|1234
```

I want to use regex to replace everything between `K11|` and `|P`. The string between these changes.
I thought this was straight forward enough but I cant get it to work.

I have tried `var regEx5 = /K11\|\w*\|P/g`
then using that string to replace the text. The regex is bringing back `QPC0amoCHidY` though. I cant understand why it is doing this. Is it because the string contains `+` symbol? Im at a loss.

Also tried `/K11\|[^|]*\|P/g` and  `/K11\|(.*?)\|P/g` with no joy

Code that is doing the regex and the replace:

```
var regEx5 = /K11\|([^|]+)\|P/g 
newText1 = newText1["replace"](regEx5, "K11|<IGNORE>|P");
```

Comment: What language are you using ? Because your 2nd and 3rd attempts work with the JavaScript regex engine.

Comment: And as it seems like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): your test string looks like a CSV line with pipe separators, are you sure that you need to extract values between `K11|` and `|P` but not just extracting the *nth* column of that CSV string ?

Comment: Yes, definitely need that specific string. It seem that the string containing two + symbols is causing the issue. If it only has one + symbol in it, '/K11\|\w*\|P/g' works. But not sure why the string containing two + symbols causes an issue.

Comment: Should add its an instrument output not CSV. Its in testcomplete and I believe the project is setup to use C#.

Comment: ok, but the 3rd attempt (`/K11\|(.*?)\|P/g`) works on all flavors listed on regex101, including *".NET (C#)"*. Maybe try without the `?`: `K11\|(.*)\|P` ?

Comment: Also I cant just replace all the + symbols as they are else where in the output and are required there

Comment: using 'K11\|(.*)\|P' still returns 'QPC0amoCHidY'. It definitely because the string contains two '+' symbols. Is there any way to tell it to ignore these symbols in the string and not treat tham as special characters? I presume that is what is happening

Comment: Are you using any code? And if you do, can you add it to the question?

Comment: I have added that, thank you

Comment: @Endorium If you are using C#, then why not use `Regex.Replace` ? See https://ideone.com/9UwCu0

Comment: `var regEx5 = /K11\|([^|]+)\|P/g` is not valid C# code, and `newText1["replace"](regEx5, "K11|<IGNORE>|P");` seems unlikely to be appropriate, too.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets of pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace a string that occurs between two other strings, a common approach is to capture the two bounding strings and then the replacement expression puts back the two captured strings with the new wanted text in the middle.

Using the RegEx `(K11\|).*(\|P)` captures the `K11|` and the `|P` in groups 1 and 2. The text between them is matched by the `.*` but it is not captured.

The question is not clear on what the replacement should be, so lets assume that it is `NewText`.

The replacement expression should then be `\1NewText\2` or `$1NewText$2` depending on the exact RegEx version being used.

C# code to perform the change could be as follows. Note that the backslash characters in the strings need to be doubled when putting them the C# strings.

```
string source = "MSH|^~\\&|dgdgd|MSH6TOMSH4|Instrument|MSH4toMSH6|20230921104820+01:00||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|QPC0amoCwk+2uSHidYKB+Q|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^";
string regex = "(K11\\|).*(\\|P)";
string replace = "$1NewText$2";
string output = Regex.Replace(source, regex, replace);

Console.WriteLine($"Was: '{source}'");
Console.WriteLine($"Now: '{output}'");
```

The output from this code is:

```
Was: 'MSH|^~\&|dgdgd|MSH6TOMSH4|Instrument|MSH4toMSH6|20230921104820+01:00||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|QPC0amoCwk+2uSHidYKB+Q|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^'
Now: 'MSH|^~\&|dgdgd|MSH6TOMSH4|Instrument|MSH4toMSH6|20230921104820+01:00||RSP^K11^RSP_K11|NewText|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8|||LAB-27R^'
```

---

A comment on the question states that

> `K11\|(.*)\|P` still returns `QPC0amoCHidY`

Where the text `QPC0amoCHidY`is part of the string between `K11|` and `|P`. In this ReGex the text that is captured is the text the should be replaced, the original `K11|` and `|P` are thus *lost*. I do not know why the rest of the text between the two strings (i.e. the `+2uSHidYKB+Q`) does not appear, but I suspect that something extra is being done in the code.

Comment: There isn't anything extra been done in the code. Its as simple as the piece I added to the questions. With one + in the strong it works fine. But as soon as the string contains two + symbols, it doesn't work. For instance qfwf+fwef+ewfw will not work. qfwf+fwef works fine. Its as if regex is seeing the 2nd + as a special character

Comment: @Endorium The two lines of code shown at the bottom of the question do not make any sense to me. The types of the various parts are not shown. The line `var regEx5 = /K11\|([^|]+)\|P/g` is not C# code as per the tags on the question. It is also hard to understand the line `newText1 = newText1["replace"](regEx5, "K11|<IGNORE>|P");` as C# code. I am sure that there is more to the code being used than is shown in the question. Just showing two lines from a larger piece of code is not sufficient.